# What was the "test" I was given on the "first questions" list about?

Tags: discussion, review

So, recently I reached 500 reputation on MSE, which gives me access to a tool in which I can review first answers and first questions. I noticed there was a question in the "First Questions" tab, so I clicked on it. It showed a question that was poorly written, so I clicked "Share feedback", but a pop-up appeared telling me it was "just a test" to make sure I was "paying attention", before taking me to the real question. (I'm not using quotation marks sarcastically, I'm literally quoting what it said) The whole situation left me feeling a little bit confused, and I was just wondering what that was about.

Comment: Definitely go read up on the review test questions, but just so you know: Everyone gets these from time to time, so you don't need to worry about getting one. What you might end up having to worry about later on is if you're frequently getting these tests wrong.

Comment: Also of note: they're supposed to be easy, and a sign that you're paying attention. If you get one wrong and are still confused afterward, please do ask about it on site-specific meta. In many cases, mods will agree and manually remove it from the list of audits.